# what does ip_route_input_noref() , ip_check_mc_rcu() and ip_route_input_mc() functions do?

Tags: c, networking, linux-kernel

Recently i was researching Linux networking subsystem. There i found these functions `ip_route_input_noref()` , `ip_check_mc_rcu()` and `ip_route_input_mc()`.I searched a lot but did not find any documentation about these functions.Would you please tell me what does these functions actually do.

Comment: In what source did you "discover" calls to those functions...?

Comment: You *do* have the ultimate documentation for the functions: The source. Read the source and try to understand what they do that way instead.

Comment: I discovered those functions in Linux Kernel Networking - Implementation and Theory this book.I searched them in google for documentation

Comment: Here is a cross-ref for the first function http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=ip_route_input_noref.  Here is its link to the actual source code:  http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/route.c#L1843   as @JoachimPileborg recommended, you can read the "ultimate" documentation to determine what it does.